# epstopdf converts color image to grayscale image

Tags: epstopdf

When I include graphics in my document the colors are converted to grayscale. I have the following in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[reqno,letter,12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\tolerance=10000
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

% Supress page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Then I include the graphic in my document:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
 \vspace{.35cm}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/20141117R268Trial8TTCIP_mask.eps}
\end{subfigure}
```

The resulting image I get looks like this:

[image: Output using epstopdf]

The image should really look like:

[image: What the output should be]

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried without the `[pdftex]` option to `graphicx`, without adding `epstopdf`, and omitting the `.eps` extension from the `\includegraphics` command? Those haven't been typically required for the last few years in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your EPS file is coloured? You can check this with GhostView (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/). If you created the figure with Matlab use

```
saveas(gcf,20141117R268Trial8TTCIP_mask.eps,'epsc')
```

the `c` stands for colour. If you only type

```
saveas(gcf,20141117R268Trial8TTCIP_mask.eps)
```

the EPS file will be gray by default.